# Error occurred while executing GetServicePrincipalOAuth2PermissionGrants

Tags: azure-ad-b2b, azure-ad-powershell-v2

My requirement is to fetch permissions granted to Azure ad application from powershell.
I have an application with few delegated permissions like this:

[image]

I found `Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOAuth2PermissionGrant`  command to achieve my scenario.

But I am facing this error, when I ran the above command:

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOAuth2PermissionGrant : Error occurred while executing GetServicePrincipalOAuth2PermissionGrants  
Code: Request_ResourceNotFound  
Message: Resource 'XXXXXXXX does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.  
RequestId: d0ed46b9-e8ea-47c0-b575-10ba67863ac6  
DateTimeStamp: Wed, 10 Aug 2022 05:59:54 GMT  
HttpStatusCode: NotFound  
HttpStatusDescription: Not Found  
HttpResponseStatus: Completed  
At line:1 char:1  
+ Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOAuth2PermissionGrant -ObjectId XXXXX...  
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
+ CategoryInfo  : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADServ...PermissionGrant], ApiException  
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetServicePrincipalOAuth2PermissionGrants
```

I have given the correct **ObjectId of the application** and I have admin role.

Help me with suggestions on how to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created an Azure AD Application and granted same **Api permissions** like below:

[image]

I tried to fetch delegated permissions by using the below command and got the **same error** as below:

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOAuth2PermissionGrant -ObjectId 6bd87ba1-29ad-4596-XXXXX
```

[image]

Please note that, Service principal of **`ObjectID`** means you have to give **`ObjectID`** of your **Enterprise Application**:

[image]

When I gave **`ObjectID`** of Enterprise Application in the below command, got the response successfully:

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOAuth2PermissionGrant -ObjectId e6029623-d410-4d8c-82ea-XXXXX | fl
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOAuth2PermissionGrant (AzureAD) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadserviceprincipaloauth2permissiongrant?view=azureadps-2.0)

Comment: Thanks, got it with Enterprise app's object ID!